# Is it possible to use LabelFor for header row in Index view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am trying to leverage DataAnnotation values in ASP.NET MVC Index view. Interesting, code generator uses field names (eg., BlogPost) as opposed to `Html.LabelFor(m => Model.ColumNames["BlogPost"])` or something similar (I made it up).

Does it mean, that if the Model is IEnumerable (as in Index view), then it is not possible to get to the Display Name that is specified by DataAnnotation? Hard to believe...

My code is currently a mix of MVC 2 and MVC 3, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should, at the very least, be able to get what you want by using a partial view (ascx for WebForms) or a Display/Editor template.  In your index page you can loop over your enumerable and pass the item into either a partial view or a template.

There may be a way to do it without having do as I've suggested (and I would be interested in seeing the answer), but what I've suggested should work fine.

EDIT:

After some clarification, here is my updated answer.

You can still get the label for a property while still respecting the `DisplayAttribute` in data annotations.  I tried this real quick and it seems to work fine.

In my view I have the following:

```
Html.LabelFor(m => m.BlogPosts.First().BlogPostTitle)
```

This worked even if there were no items in the enumeration itself.  When I first tested this I got the property name, then I added decorated the property with the `DisplayAttribute` and the value of the name property was displayed instead of the standard property name.

Comment: thanks, but I think you misunderstood my question. The issue is *not* how to loop over enumerable. The issue is to how to show Display Names in the *header row* in the index view (where I show a table of values from DB) - that is, **before** I started looping. I am not clear how partial view or Display template applies to the question.

Comment: You are right, I did misunderstand.  I did not realize you were listing in a tabular format.  I've looked into this some and I believe if have you answer.  I will modify my answer to include this new information.

Comment: Hmm... I can swear I got a problem when I tried First()... Either the problem was with an empty set, or it was swallowing the row, or I couldn't have two First() in the header, or I was smoking something illegal. In any event, it's working fine indeed. BTW, you probably meant DisplayName, not DisplayAttribute.

Comment: I hadn't realized that before.  There's a System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute and a System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute.  I was using the DisplayAttribute, but it sounds like you are using DisplayName, but both seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

In MVC 4, the [HtmlHelper extensions in the DisplayNameExtensions class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) allows the following (this is the default scaffolding of a list with column headings)

```
@model IEnumerable<Entity.Foo>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Bar)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bar)
        </td>
...
```

This is because DisplayNameFor has overloads for both `TModel` and `IEnumerable<TModel>`:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>
                       (this HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>> html, 
                        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression);
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>
                       (this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
                        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression);
```

Comment: Nice find, code completion doesn't seem to work with the `IEnumerable` overload so it's easy to overlook.

Comment: This only works if your view model itself is an IEnumerable such as in the views generated by the scaffolding framework. This is bad practice since you should stick to using dedicated view model classes.